# Shape/Throttle an IP on the network (QoS)

Tags: networking, server

I've got a server running 12.04 set up as a modem. DHCP, NAT, etc.

I need to know how to reduce the speed of a single IP on the network or set the speed of each individual IP.

My problem is my brother's GF keeps running torrents 24/7 , making my internet horribly slow. Asking her to stop hasn't worked, so now I need to control her connection.

I think my options are either limiting her to, say 4mbps down and 300kbps up... or throwing QoS at her. I've no idea how to do either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend reading the [Linux Advanced Routing & Traffic Control HOWTO](http://lartc.org/howto/), in particular the examples on [rate limiting a single host or netmask](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.ratelimit.single.html) and [a full nat solution with QoS](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.cookbook.fullnat.intro.html).

Essentially you have to do the following:

- Mark packets from that particular host in the `PREROUTING` chain of the `mangle` table
- Set up some prioritizing or rate limiting traffic control
- Make sure the market packets fall into the low priority resp. limited class

Untested, but something along these lines (feel free to edit if you notice a mistake):

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -s 192.168.0.666 -j MARK --set-mark 1
tc qdisc add dev ppp0 root handle 1: cbq avpkt 1000 bandwidth 10mbit 
tc class add dev ppp0 parent 1: classid 1:1 cbq rate 512kbit \
   allot 1500 prio 5 bounded isolated 
tc filter add dev ppp0 parent 1: protocol ip prio 1 handle 1 fw classid 1:1
```

Notice that you can't directly use `tc filter` to filter on the IP of that host, since the tc filter applies *after* NAT, so it will see your public IP, which cannot be used to differentiate the packet.

Usually you'd rate-limit upstream packets, since there you have the most control, and since on a common ADSL link the upstream is more easily saturated by p2p traffic. If you want, you can also attempt to rate-limit the downstream by deliberately dropping packets. You'd do that using another traffic control setup, this time for packets forwarded over the local network device.